# lim sup , lim inf based problem

Tags: real-analysis

> Define the sequence $a_n$ as follows:
>
> $a_1=1$ and for $n\geq 1$ $$a_{n+1}=(-1)^n\Bigg(\frac{1}{2}\Bigg)\Bigg(\vert a_n \vert+ \frac{2}{\vert a_n \vert}\Bigg) $$
>
> Which of the following is true?
>
> - $\limsup a_n=\sqrt{2}$
> - $\liminf a_n=-\infty$
> - $\lim a_n=\sqrt{2}$
> - $\sup a_n=\sqrt{2}$

If the given sequence is convergent then $1$ and $3$ options are correct. But only one option is correct. If we find $a_2,a_3,a_4,...$ Then option $1$ is correct. But method time consuming and not good. Please help me to solve it by easiest method.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.